# Stationary distribution of the embedded MC

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let *Q* be an infinitesimal generator:
$$Q=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & 0&0&0&0 \\
    0 & -2 & 2 &0&0&0 \\
    0 & 0 & -3&3&0&0 \\
0&0&0&-4&-4&0 \\
0&0&0&0&-5&5 \\
6&0&0&0&0&-6
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
Calculate the stationary probability distribution of the CTMC from the stationary distribution of its embedded MC.

---

If I am correct, the embedded MC is in this case $$W=
    \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 0&0&0&0 \\
0 & 0 & 1&0&0&0 \\
0 & 0 & 0&1&0&0 \\
0 & 0 & 0&0&1&0 \\
1 & 0 & 0&0&0&0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$,
since the probabilities of remaining in states (diagonals) are 0.
Now I probably need to find an invariant vector but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: The matrix is doubly stochastic (both rows and columns sum to one), so the unique stationary distribution is the uniform distribution.

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting because when I calculated it using the other method (solving equations) I got (1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6) which normalized gave (0.408, 0.204, 0.136, 0.102, 0.08, 0.068). I have probably made a mistake somewhere